# Plot specific values coming in a sequence from a matrix in a another color

Tags: arrays, matlab, matlab-figure

I am plotting my `matrix <1x10000>` which consists of values such as:

```
30, 30, 30, 60, 60, 60, 25, 25, 25, 25, 70, 70, 70, 10, 10, 10 and so on...
```

which gives me a horizontal line as  I want. Now I want to select another color or add a label or whatever you find handy where the line is plotted for the values `60, 25, 70` (how many they are doesn't matter, but they must come in that order).

### Example:

We have a graph plotted from a matrix. The matrix consists of these values:

```
myMatrix = [30, 30, 30, 60, 60, 60, 25, 25, 25, 25, 70, 70, 70, 10, 10, 10]
```

this gives a blue line `plot(myMatrix, 'b')`.
Now I want to make the whole sequence of 60, 25, 70 plotted in another color, or have some kind of label that shows: "here is a sequence of `60, 25, 70`. So, `30, 30, 30` would be in blue, `60, 60, 60, 25, 25, 25, 25, 70, 70, 70` would be in another color or have a label next to the line, and the then `10, 10, 10` would be in blue.

Important to point out is that the values must come in the exact sequence/copy, in other words, `60, 25, 70` would work for:

```
60, 60, 60, 25, 25, 70, 70, 70
```

but

```
60, 60, 60, 80, 70, 70
```

would not be colored in another color than blue.

Apologies if the explanation is "a bit how ya doin!". Totally new in Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code for both finding and plotting:

```
myMatrix = [30, 30, 30, 60, 60, 60, 25, 25, 25, 25, 70, 70, 70, 10, 10, 10];
d = diff([myMatrix(1) myMatrix]); % find all switches between diferent elements
len = 1:numel(myMatrix); % make a list of all indices in myMatrix
idx = [len(d~=0)-1 numel(myMatrix)]; % the index of the end each group
counts = [idx(1) diff(idx)]; % the number of elements in the group
elements = myMatrix(idx); % the type of element
n_groups = numel(idx); % the no. of groups in the vector

values = [60 25 70];
mask = zeros(1,numel(myMatrix));
for k = 1:n_groups-numel(values)+1
    if isequal(values,elements(k:k+numel(values)-1))
        if k>1
            mask(idx(k-1)+1:idx(k+numel(values)-1)) = 1;
        else
            mask(1:idx(k+numel(values)-1)) = 1;
        end
    end
end
imagesc(mask)
colormap([0 0 1;0 1 0])
axis image
axis off
```

which gives:

[image: plot_vector]

and for:

```
myMatrix = [1 2 3 2 1 2 1 2 3 2 1 3 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3];
values = [1 2 3];
```

we get:

[image: 123_vec]

Comment: @Lasse, let me know if this answers your question, and if so, please consider accepting/upvote it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and reminding me, upvoted and accepted :)